# CRC32 Collision Of Hashes Created From First 10^5 Integers?

Tags: php, hash, unique

I'm trying to create array of 100.000 unique 8 character strings. for input I have array of integers from 1 to 100.000. I'm planing to use crc32. Can I assume there wont be any collisions?
P.S. I'm worrying only about collisions..

Comment: This is a simple case of "try it and see". There is no need to use crc32() and only the simple integers as input, generating unique 8 character strings can be done by simply doing aaaaaaaa aaaaaaab etc. If you have any other requirements about guessability etc, 8 characters may not be enough (at least not when using only [a-f0-9]. You might want to expand your question with more details.

Comment: Sounds like homework from school

Comment: @Akhil - why use a 128-bit hash when a 33-bit CRC-32 would be perfectly adequate?

Comment: If unique is the only requirement `for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++) $result[] = 'A'.(1000000 + $i);` Any particular reason to use crc32?

Comment: @MarkBaker check the above ques

Comment: @Akhil - yes, he could use md5. My point is, why should he use md5 when a crc32 result is 4 times smaller, and generating a CRC is faster than generating an md5

Comment: @MarkBaker http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php

crc in php is not much portable , error probability is there ..

Comment: @fiskfisk - actually I want 8 char/digits string which looks like random one.. i don't want: 1 - aaaaaaaa, 2 - aaaaaaab. I need strictly 8 characters in string so crc32 looked ok.. i'm using $v_code = hash ("crc32", $userID) ($userID is auto-increment value in db) to generate numbers and put them into db, but i don't want to use random function, because then i need to check existence of newly created string...

Comment: @Akhil - Cropping md5 looks totally unsafe

Comment: @inemanja Then anyone can generate a valid key for any user if they discover the relation between their userid and the key. You're better off creating actual random strings.

Comment: @inemanja You say that "cropping md5 looks totally unsafe". Generally speaking that's true, but the bomttom line is that it depends on what and how you plan to use it for.

Comment: @fiskfisk - generated number is sort of voucher for some kind of lottery, so it is not important if anyone can find out which string is generated. i just wanted to use string that looks random, but it can be generated and used for generating confirmation string - md5($vaucher_no . $user_email)... edit: i may have to change way of creating confirmation string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here's your answer.**](http://codepad.org/9YbLe3Nn)

```
$result = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100000; ++$i) $result[sprintf('_%u', crc32($i))] = true;

if (count($result) == 100000)
{
    echo 'Yes, you can use CRC32.';
}

else
{
    echo 'Ooops, you better use another algorithm.';
}
```

Comment: this is ok, I just need to replace `$result[sprintf('_%u', crc32($i))] = true` with `$result[hash("crc32",$userID)]`  Thanks!